# Use ADSL Modem as ROUTER WITH DHCP?

Tags: networking, router, modem

This is a beginner's question. But before answering or marking it as possible duplicate please make sure that you understand that **I DON'T WANT A SWITCH OR A BRIDGE.** I want an Ethernet Router.

So I have a NETGEAR DG834G V5. I've moved into a building where I get static IP in my room. But the Modem that I have does not include a WAN port for the Network cable.

Is there a one-to-one analogy between the LAN cable and Telephone cable? In that sense maybe I could buy a "Converter" From the LAN at the wall and the ADSL port on the Modem, and set the static IP setting for my modem?

**EDIT**: Another Idea would be to set static IP for one of the four LAN ports to use it as WAN, and set the DHCP as normal for the wifi. Is that Possible?

Comment: That device _is_ a router. It routes between an ADSL network and your ethernet/Wi-Fi network. It cannot route between two ethernet networks.

Comment: For your edit, the LAN interfaces are on the built-in switch module, they are not router interfaces. The router has two interfaces: the ADSL WAN interface, and an internal LAN interface that connects to the switch module.

Answer (score 1):

The four ethernet ports are only able to be used as a switch.

The ADSL interface of the router you have cannot be converted to ethernet without buying very expensive equipment called a DSLAM which typically is situted at an ADSL enabled exchange.

Your best bet is to buy a router with an ethernet WAN interface and use that or, if you have a PC that can take another network interface, use that as a router.